# Enable Opportunity Splits - Scratch Org

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file, opportunity-split

Working with scratch orgs, I need to enable OpportunitySplits completely at the point of **Scratch Org Creation, and Source Push**.

Currently, when successfully pushing the below files and settings. The Opportunity Split Settings page still prompts the user to have to manually enable this.

How can I enable this in the Scratch Org so that I don't have to rely on a manual step?
Thanks!

[image: Opportunity Splits Settings page]

**Below Files**

`project-scratch-def.json`

```
{
    "orgName": "OrgName",
    "edition": "Enterprise",
    "features": [
      "API",
      "PersonAccounts",
      "Knowledge",
      "Communities",
      "ServiceCloud",
      "StateAndCountryPicklist",
      "CustomerCommunityPlus",
      "PublishAuraExpBuilderBasedSna",
      "PublishExpBuilderBasedSna",
      "ContactsToMultipleAccounts"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "experienceBundleSettings": {
            "enableExperienceBundleMetadata": true
        },
        "communitiesSettings": {
            "enableNetworksEnabled": true
        },
        "lightningExperienceSettings": {
            "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
        },
        "chatterSettings": {
            "enableChatter": true
        },
        "pathAssistantSettings": {
            "pathAssistantEnabled" : true
        },
        "accountSettings": {
            "enableRelateContactToMultipleAccounts": true,
            "enableAccountTeams" : true
        },
        "customAddressFieldSettings" : {
            "enableCustomAddressField" : true
        },
        "opportunitySettings": {
            "enableOpportunityTeam" : true
        }
        

    } 
  }
```

`sfdx-project.json`

```
{
    "packageDirectories": [
      {
        "path": "force-app",
        "default": true
      }
    ],
    "namespace": "",
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "sourceApiVersion": "55.0"
}
```

`Account.settings-meta.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AccountSettings xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <enableAccountHistoryTracking>false</enableAccountHistoryTracking>
    <enableAccountTeams>true</enableAccountTeams>
    <enableContactHistoryTracking>false</enableContactHistoryTracking>
    <enableRelateContactToMultipleAccounts>true</enableRelateContactToMultipleAccounts>
    <showViewHierarchyLink>true</showViewHierarchyLink>
</AccountSettings>
```

`Opportunity.settings-meta.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OpportunitySettings xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <autoActivateNewReminders>true</autoActivateNewReminders>
    <customizableProductSchedulesEnabled>false</customizableProductSchedulesEnabled>
    <doesEnforceStandardOpportunitySaveLogic>true</doesEnforceStandardOpportunitySaveLogic>
    <enableFindSimilarOpportunities>false</enableFindSimilarOpportunities>
    <enableOpportunityFieldHistoryTracking>false</enableOpportunityFieldHistoryTracking>
    <enableOpportunityTeam>true</enableOpportunityTeam>
    <enableUpdateReminders>true</enableUpdateReminders>
    <oppAmountDealMotionEnabled>true</oppAmountDealMotionEnabled>
    <oppCloseDateDealMotionEnabled>true</oppCloseDateDealMotionEnabled>
    <promptToAddProducts>false</promptToAddProducts>
    <simpleOppCreateFromContact>true</simpleOppCreateFromContact>
    <simpleOppCreateFromEvent>true</simpleOppCreateFromEvent>
</OpportunitySettings>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like splits enablement is not currently supported in scratch orgs via SFDX.

Recommend upvoting related ideas:
https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdcUxUAJ/opportunity-splits-tracked-in-metadata

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdb7rUAB/salesforce-dx-scratch-org-definition-file-should-allow-all-salesforce-settings

You can make use of [Org Shape feature](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_shape_intro.htm)

When we use Org Shape, it exactly takes the settings and features from the source org and the Scratch Orgs will be created exactly as a replica of source org implying if opportunity Splits is enabled in the source org, then it is copied over to scratch orgs.